# How to fix C string inverse function bug?

Tags: c

I am trying to write a function that can inverse the string contents. But when I run the program, it cannot work properly......
So my question is :
Can somebody tell me what is the problem of this code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define ARR "It's a perfect day\n"

char * string_in(char *, int);
int main(void)
{
    char * ptr = ARR, ans;
    size_t size = strlen(ARR);
    printf("%d\n", size);
    do
    {
        puts(ptr);
        ans = string_in(ARR, size);
        puts(ptr);
    }while(getchar() == '\n');

    return 0;
}

char * string_in(char * tar, int n)
{
    char temp;
    int index = n - 1;

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        temp = *(tar+i);
        tar[i] = tar[index];
        tar[index] = temp;
        index--;
    }

    return tar;
}
```

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`). Then **use the debugger** (`gdb`)

Comment: String literal must not be changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second loop should go only till (n/2)

```
for(int i = 0; i < (n/2); i++)
```

Answer (score 2):

You must be getting the segmentation fault because of this:

```
#define ARR "It's a perfect day\n"
```

And when you are doing like below:

```
char * ptr = ARR;
```

This will be replaced by compiler as:

```
char * ptr = "It's a perfect day\n";
```

and above sting is immutable which you can't modified. Therefore, segmentation fault.

And yes please correct your reverse string function. And declare ARR as `char ARR[length]` with `length` of required number of chars in array.

Answer (score 0):

Write the function the following way

```
char * reverse( char * s, size_t n )
{
    for( size_t i = 0; i < n / 2; i++ )
    {
        char tmp = s[i];
        s[i] = s[n - i - 1];
        s[n - i - 1] = tmp;
    }

    return s;
}
```

As for your function then it at first reverses it when i < n / 2 and then reverses it second time to its original state.